# How to control randomness when training word2vec in Gensim?

Tags: python, random, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm working on the gensim’s word2vec model, but different runs on the same dataset produce the different model. I tried to set seed to a fixed number, including  PYTHONHASHSEED and set the number of workers being one. But all the above methods are not working.

I included my code here:

```
def word2vec_model(data):
    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(data, size=300, window=20, workers=4, min_count=1)
    model.wv.save("word2vec.wordvectors")
    embed = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load("word2vec.wordvectors", mmap='r')
    return embed
```

I checked the following output:

```
Cooking.similar_by_vector(Cooking['apple'], topn=10, restrict_vocab=None)
```

example output:

```
[('apple', 0.9999999403953552),
 ('charcoal', 0.2554503381252289),
 ('response', 0.25395694375038147),
 ('boring', 0.2537640631198883),
 ('healthy', 0.24807702004909515),
 ('wrong', 0.24783077836036682),
 ('juice', 0.24270494282245636),
 ('lacta', 0.2373320758342743),
 ('saw', 0.2359238862991333),
 ('insufferable', 0.23015251755714417)]
```

Each run, I got different similar words.

Does anyone know how to solve it？I appreciate any direct codes or documentation. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you're setting `PYTHONHASHSEED`. It must be set **before** the Python-interpreter is run to prevent Python's built-in string-hash randomization - so you *can't* set it from within Python.

But also: in general, you shouldn't be trying to eliminate the small jitter in results from run-to-run. It's an inherent part of these algorithms - especially when run in realistic, efficient modes (like with many training threads). Even if you succeed, you'll wind up in a very-slow (single-threaded-training) mode, and the stability of the results can mislead you about what can be expected in realistic deployments.

There's more discussion of this same point in the Gensim FAQ:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vec--doc2vec--etc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism

Separately, using `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea. These algorithms can't make good vectors for words that only have a single usage example, and generally give better results when rare words are discarded, as happens with the default `min_count=5` value. (It is especially the case that if you have enough training data to justify big 300-dimensional word-vectors, you should likely be increasing, rather than decreasing, the default `min_count=5` cutoff.)